# How to automatically generate docstrings including nested functions?

Tags: python, documentation, docstring, pydoc, pdoc

How to generate automatically docs for the `c_nested` function?

Background: I do code documentation for other developers and I would like to automatically generate a summary of all class methods included nested functions with short description (docstring).

When I run `help(A)` on class `A` I get:

```
Help on class A in module __main__:

class A(builtins.object)
 |  A(a)
 |  
 |  doc A
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, a)
 |      Initialize self.  See 
 |  
 |  b_method(self)
 |      doc b_method
```

Requested output: `c_nested()` with docstring: (Docs could be printed event with script, it doesn't need to be printed with pydoc help.)

```
Help on class A in module __main__:

class A(builtins.object)
 |  A(a)
 |  
 |  doc A
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, a)
 |      Initialize self.  See 
 |  
 |  b_method(self)
 |      doc b_method
 |
 |           c_nested()
 |                doc c_nested
```

Class example:

```
class A:
    """ doc A """
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

    def b_method(self):
        """ doc b_method """

        def c_nested():
            """doc  c_nested """
            pass

        return c_nested()
```

Answer (score 2):

Local functions are not publicly visible, so their docstring won't be included in the help.

If you want the function to be shown in the help, make it a module-level function or a method of the class.

See also [Are docstrings for internal functions (python) necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687407/are-docstrings-for-internal-functions-python-necessary)

Comment: thanks for info, but it will not solve the problem, I'm creating code documentation for other developers and I would like to generate automatically summary of all class methods included nested functions.

Comment: Nested functions cannot be called, why would you want to include them in your public documentation?